# Drop down interface from top of page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Quite simply, I want to know how I can do this 'http://www.lido-troon.co.uk/'.

Where it says 'Reserve a table'. This trigger allows a drop down interface to animate as if from above.

I'm not interested in the booking system in there, just the functionality.

I thought it could be done using anchors and smooth scroll, but that would mean the booking form was always there.

Comment: The fact that this is tagged "java" frightens me deeply.

Comment: it is always there as div#placeholder-bookings with a display of "none".  It is positioned "relative" and scrolled into view (most likely) using JQuery once the link is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

I will give you a code that will center this div on the top of the screen on every screen and will slide the div down from the top onLoad:

HTML:

```
<div id="ID_NAME">Your Content</div>
```

JQuery:

```
jQuery.fn.center = function () {
   this.css("position","absolute");
   this.css("top","-100px"); 
   this.css("left", (($(window).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft() + "px");return this;
 }
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#ID_NAME').center().delay(300).animate({'top' : '0px'});
});
```

Hope this helped

Answer (score 0):

Create the content and then show it using JQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 0):

You can have the top div with your booking system content hidden with `jQuery's hide()` than on `.click()` of the button (a tag), have it `slideDown()`

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('booking_div').hide();
    $('booking_a').click(function() {
        $('booking_div').slideDown();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript, Jquery. that have many UI effect. It's good and easy to use. You can learning it from document. e.g. http://www.webdesignersblog.net/coding/20-advanced-jquery-effects/ http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can,
create div at the top of your page with the style="display: none;" or set class with the css from style attribute. Then attach event click to your link and animate change.

**JavaScript**

```
   $('#your_link_button').click(function()
        {
            $("#container").slideToggle('slow');          

        });
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="container" class="hidden">your content</div>
...
```